# ipa-server installation failed

Tags: linux, redhat, freeipa

facing a problem when install ipa-server .
the problem is :

Configured /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

trying https://ipa.cse.local/ipa/json

[try 1]: Forwarding 'schema' to json server 'https://ipa.cse.local/ipa/json'

cannot connect to 'https://ipa.cse.local/ipa/json': [Errno 111] Connection refused

The ipa-client-install command failed. See /var/log/ipaclient-install.log for more information

ipapython.admintool: ERROR    Configuration of client side components failed!

ipapython.admintool: ERROR    The ipa-server-install command failed. See /var/log/ipaserver-install.log for more information

/var/log/ipaserver-install | tail -n 70  :-

[root@ipa ~]# cat /var/log/ipaserver-install.log | tail -n 70

2020-10-27T04:24:43Z DEBUG dnszone_show(, rights=False, all=False, raw=False, version=u'2.237')

2020-10-27T04:24:43Z DEBUG raw: location_find(None, version=u'2.237')

2020-10-27T04:24:43Z DEBUG location_find(None, all=False, raw=False, version=u'2.237', pkey_only=False)

2020-10-27T04:24:43Z DEBUG Changing admin password

2020-10-27T04:24:43Z DEBUG Starting external process

2020-10-27T04:24:43Z DEBUG args=/usr/bin/ldappasswd -h ipa.cse.local -ZZ -x -D cn=Directory Manager -y /var/lib/ipa/tmpMIlydW -T /var/lib/ipa/tmpUxswyc uid=admin,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=cse,dc=local

2020-10-27T04:24:44Z DEBUG Process finished, return code=0
2020-10-27T04:24:44Z DEBUG stdout=

2020-10-27T04:24:44Z DEBUG stderr=

2020-10-27T04:24:44Z DEBUG ldappasswd done

2020-10-27T04:24:44Z DEBUG Configuring client side components

2020-10-27T04:24:44Z DEBUG Starting external process

2020-10-27T04:24:44Z DEBUG args=/usr/sbin/ipa-client-install --on-master --unattended --domain cse.local --server ipa.cse.local --realm CSE.LOCAL --hostname ipa.cse.local

2020-10-27T04:24:49Z DEBUG Process finished, return code=1

2020-10-27T04:24:49Z DEBUG   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipapython/admintool.py", line 178, in execute
return_value = self.run()

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipapython/install/cli.py", line 319, in run
return cfgr.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 360, in run

```
return self.execute()
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 386, in execute

```
for rval in self._executor():
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 431, in __runner
exc_handler(exc_info)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 460, in _handle_execute_exception

```
self._handle_exception(exc_info)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 450, in _handle_exception

```
six.reraise(*exc_info)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 421, in __runner

```
step()
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 418, in

step = lambda: next(self.__gen)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipapython/install/util.py", line 81, in run_generator_with_yield_from

```
six.reraise(*exc_info)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipapython/install/util.py", line 59, in run_generator_with_yield_from

```
value = gen.send(prev_value)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 655, in _configure

```
next(executor)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 431, in __runner

```
exc_handler(exc_info)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 460, in _handle_execute_exception

```
self._handle_exception(exc_info)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 518, in _handle_exception

```
self.__parent._handle_exception(exc_info)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 450, in _handle_exception

```
six.reraise(*exc_info)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 515, in _handle_exception

```
super(ComponentBase, self)._handle_exception(exc_info)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 450, in _handle_exception

```
six.reraise(*exc_info)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 421, in __runner

```
step()
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipapython/install/core.py", line 418, in

```
step = lambda: next(self.__gen)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipapython/install/util.py", line 81, in run_generator_with_yield_from
six.reraise(*exc_info)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipapython/install/util.py", line 59, in run_generator_with_yield_from
value = gen.send(prev_value)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipapython/install/common.py", line 65, in _install

```
for unused in self._installer(self.parent):
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipaserver/install/server/**init**.py", line 590, in main

```
master_install(self)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipaserver/install/server/install.py", line 250, in decorated

```
func(installer)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipaserver/install/server/install.py", line 914, in install

```
raise ScriptError("Configuration of client side components failed!")
```

2020-10-27T04:24:49Z DEBUG The ipa-server-install command failed, exception: ScriptError: Configuration of client side components failed!

2020-10-27T04:24:49Z ERROR Configuration of client side components failed!

2020-10-27T04:24:49Z ERROR The ipa-server-install command failed. See

/var/log/ipaserver-install.log for more information
[root@ipa ~]#

what can i do now ????

Comment: Do what it told you to do: check the log file!

Comment: i already provide last 20 logs of /var/log ipaserver-install.log .

Comment: You'll need to look at more than 20 lines!

Comment: i already eidt this post .and add 70 log line... please ,check it

Answer (score 0):

I worked through this same issue.  The problem was packages being drawn in from EPEL or IUS.  Specifically in my case, was httpd24u from IUS.  An installation using the following allowed for the ipa-server-install command to complete.

`yum --disablerepo IUSREPONAME install ipa-server ipa-server-dns`